# How to use map in the following condition

Tags: map

Document has link to platform (parent).Its only link to platform.

junction platform is junction object between platform and account

How to get the "accountname" based on platform.

My for loop is on "document". How to get the "account" names based on "platform"

```
 global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc,List<Document__c>scope)
{
  for(Document__c doc:scope){
        platformIds.add(doc.Platform__c);
 }

     List<Junction_Platform__c> junctionPlat=[select id,Account__c,Account__r.name,Platform__c from Junction_Platform__c where Platform__c in:platformIds];
   for(Junction_Platform__c junc:junctionPlat){
       platformmap.put(junc.Platform__c,junc);
          }

          for(Document__c doc1:scope){
            platformmap.get(doc.Platform__c).Account__r.name;
          }}
```

Problem:
             suppose

```
         account1 -->platform1 and account2-->platform1
```

In my case platform 1 is key so value will override I will get only one account name. I need both the account names

Comment: Create a `Map<Id, List<String>>` i.e. accountId as Key and Value as List of Platform

Comment: see i dont have any account link on document. finally i have to iterate through document

Comment: So you can reverse that your key can be Platform and List<Account> as values but then what further processing you need to do it depends on that.

Comment: Is there any relation between Account and Platform?

Comment: yes its linked through junction platform

Comment: What if you get `Map<PlatformId,List<Account>>` what further processing you need to do?

Comment: I need to display account names based on platform.   here i have to display for(Document__c doc1:scope){
            platformmap.get(doc.Platform__c).Account__r.name;
          }}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76952/discussion-between-rcs-and-annappa-ph).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Map<String, List<String>` where key will be `Platform__c` and values will be `List of AccountNames`

Check below piece of code

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc,List<Document__c>scope)
{
  for(Document__c doc:scope){
        platformIds.add(doc.Platform__c);
  }

  Map<String, List<String>> platformIdVsAccountListMap = new Map<String, List<String>>();

  for(Junction_Platform__c junc:[select id,Account__c,Account__r.name,Platform__c from Junction_Platform__c where Platform__c in:platformIds]){
       if(!platformIdVsAccountListMap.containsKey(junc.Platform__c))
            platformIdVsAccountListMap.put(junc.Platform__c, new List<String>{junc.Account__r.name})
       else
            platformIdVsAccountListMap.get(junc.Platform__c).add(junc.Account__r.name);
  }

  for(Document__c doc1:scope){
    for(String accName: platformIdVsAccountListMap.get(doc.Platform__c)){
         //YOU GET ALL THE ACCOUNT NAME RELATED TO A Platform__c WHAT'S THE FURTHER LOGIC?
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 1 after discussion on chat @Annappa update your question as per our chat**

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc,List<Document__c>scope)
{
  Map<
  for(Document__c doc:scope){
        platformIds.add(doc.Platform__c);
  }

  Map<String, String> platformIdVsAccountNamesMap = new Map<String, String>();

  for(Junction_Platform__c junc:[select id,Account__c,Account__r.name,Platform__c from Junction_Platform__c where Platform__c in:platformIds]){
       if(!platformIdVsAccountNamesMap.containsKey(junc.Platform__c))
            platformIdVsAccountNamesMap.put(junc.Platform__c, junc.Account__r.name)
       else
            platformIdVsAccountNamesMap.put(junc.Platform__c,platformIdVsAccountNamesMap.get(junc.Platform__c)+';'+junc.Account__r.name);
  }

  for(Document__c doc1:scope){
    String accountNames = platformIdVsAccountNamesMap.get(doc1.Platform__c);
    //YOU GET ALL THE ACCOUNT NAME RELATED TO A Platform__c WHAT'S THE FURTHER LOGIC?
  }
}
```